# Cmd script to set the hintpath in .net projects

Tags: replace, cmd

I am trying, withouth much luck, to create a bat or cmd file that would change a "corrupt" hintpath of my third party dll's so that it referes to my fixed dll path (the P-drive).  The script would have to: 
1) loop through all folders under my main projects folder finding all files with the .csproj ending 
2) loop through each file and replace every instance of "< HintPath >c:\xx\yy\q.dll< /HintPath >" to "< HintPath >P:\q.dll< /HintPath >"

thanks,

regards,
styrmir

Answer (score 2):

If possible, I would highly suggest to use **PowerShell** to perform this task. Here is what it would take to do what you are after:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.csproj -Path YOUR_TARGET_ROOT_DIRECTORY_HERE |
    ForEach-Object {
        (Get-Content $_.FullName) |
        ForEach-Object {
            $_.Replace('<HintPath>c:\xx\yy\q.dll</HintPath>', '<HintPath>P:\q.dll</HintPath>')
        } |
        Set-Content $_.FullName -WhatIf
    }
```

Note: I have included a *-WhatIf switch* that prevents the script to make any change and just outputs the actions it would perform to the console window. Please remove it to make the script functional.

**UPDATE**

To replace every possible *HintPath* reference to `q.dll` within *C:*, at every possible directory depth, you may replace this line:

```
$_.Replace('<HintPath>c:\xx\yy\q.dll</HintPath>', '<HintPath>P:\q.dll</HintPath>')
```

with this one:

```
$_ -replace '\<HintPath\>C:\\.*\\q.dll\</HintPath\>', '<HintPath>P:\q.dll</HintPath>'
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I am going to try this using the powershell.  Just out of curiosity, do you know how I would alter the suggested script so that \xx\yy are wildcards of different length - i.e. some paths might be c:\xx\yy\q.dll while others might be c:\zz\rr\mm\dd\o.dll?

Comment: You are welcome, I have updated my reply to match your new answer.